# Implicit declaration of dlsym is invalid in c99

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.2, osx-lion, c99

I have the required import in the file. I am trying to import an existing project and compile in Xcode(4.2). Do I need to include anything else?

[image]

Comment: The code in `/usr/include/dlfcn.h` on Mac OS X Lion declares `dlsym()` unconditionally; the only define that would prevent it from being declared is the header guard `_DLFCN_H_` which is there to prevent damage if the file is included multiple times. I don't know enough Objective C to know whether `#import` has any other connotations than `#include` does, but since `dlsym()` and `RTLD_SELF` are missing, there appears to be some key difference. Look for unexpected files `dlfcn.h` other than in `/usr/include`. If worst comes to worst, add `#error I am ere` to the header to ensure it is used.

Comment: I couldn't find any `dlfcn.h` file on my machine or guard `_DLFCN_H_` in any of the files, other than this import statement `#import <dlfcn.h>`. I don't see any such file in `/usr/include` either.

Comment: Not being able to find the file is puzzling.  Have you tried looking under `/Developer`?  I didn't find much there (but `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/include/dlfcn.h` was one find), but I do have (possibly old) stuff in `/usr/include`.  Have you been able to build other projects successfully?

Comment: The recursive `grep` is taking its time; I also found `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/dlfcn.h` and similar files for some other versions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ya its there, couldn't find through finder and spotlight. This is my first start with iOS, the first ever project I am trying to import.

Comment: Now how should I go about finding the bug? Is there something missing in this file?

Comment: What happens if you do the pure C equivalent, using `#include` rather than `#import`? And shouldn't this question be tagged objective-c?

Comment: What about [this small C program](https://gist.github.com/2012465)?

Comment: `➜  /Developer  gcc -c c.c
➜  /Developer  gcc -c c.c -o c -ldl
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -ldl: linker input file unused because linking not done
➜  /Developer  `

Comment: @Ava: Did [the C program](https://gist.github.com/2012465) compile and link correctly for you?  Is the "implicit declaration" message a warning from Xcode, or is it actually from the compiler?  I've never used Xcode, so I'm not sure I can be of any further help.

Comment: Yes it did in terminal after removing -c as you suggested. Its an error, my build is failing. No problem. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both errors were fixed by enclosing the the method in:

```
#ifdef RTLD_SELF

      //initialize method

#endif
```

Got hint from http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-45.1/unit-tests/test-cases/dlsym-RTLD_SELF/main.c?txt